# Android studio 3.3 doesn't show the exact error on build failure

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is happening after upgrading studio where you don't see errors in the build tab when you run the app and studio just says `Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`
and then you have to run
`./gradlew assembleDebug --stack trace` to see the actual errors.
so how to get specific compilation errors without running command `./gradlew assembleDebug --stack trace` in android studio 3.0?

Comment: Is this a question or a tutorial?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Sorry it is a question. How can I get compilation error causes by default instead of running `./gradlew assembleDebug --stack trace`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that was your problem, but you should find your errors right there.

There is a toggle button just below the build button that will show the verbose build logs

Please check following 2 capture images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Build tab on studio doesn't report any errors. I think the issue is with the Kotlin compilation